# Bootstrap's Dropdown appears below the table

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, dropdown

I'm trying to open a Bootstrap dropdown inside a table, after a button click. But the dropdown appears below the table, always in the same position, no matter which button is pressed.

Does someone had the same problem? Is it some css position that I am missing?

My goal is: each dropdown must appear just below the button that was press.

Here is a Demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filteredList = [];
   $scope.servers = [
      {
        name: 'Server 1',
        port: 5014
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 2',
        port: 5015
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 3',
        port: 5016
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 4',
        port: 5017
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 5',
        port: 5018
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 6',
        port: 5019
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 7',
        port: 5020
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 8',
        port: 8081
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 9',
        port: 8082
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 10',
        port: 8083
      }
    ];
  
  
  $scope.orderByField = "name";
  $scope.orderByReverse = false;            
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;

  $scope.orderBy = function(field) {
      if (field == $scope.orderByField)
          $scope.orderByReverse = !$scope.orderByReverse
      else {
          $scope.orderByField = field;
          $scope.orderByReverse = false;
      }
  };

  
})

.factory('Utils', function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        getNormalizedString: getNormalizedString,
        setFocus: setFocus
    }

    function getNormalizedString(str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'), "");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'), "a");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'), "ae");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'), "c");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'), "e");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'), "i");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("ñ", 'g'), "n");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'), "o");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'), "oe");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'), "u");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'), "y");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'), "");
        return str;
    }

    function setFocus(id) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
            if (element)
                element.focus();
        });
    }
})

.filter('normalizedOrderBy', function(Utils, $filter) {
    return function(list, orderByField, orderByReverse) {
        function normalize(item) {
            var value = item[orderByField];
            if (typeof value === "string")
                value = Utils.getNormalizedString(value);

            // Forces the empty names to the end.
            if (value === null || value === "")
                return '~';

            return value;
        };

        return $filter('orderBy')(list, normalize, orderByReverse);
    }
})

.filter('normalizedFilter', function(Utils, $filter) {
    return function(list, search) {
        function comparator(actual, expected) {
            // Filtro vazio ou nulo.
            if (expected === "" || expected == null)
                return true;
            // Exatamente iguais.
            if (actual == expected)
                return true;

            if (typeof actual === "string" && typeof expected === "string") {
                actual = Utils.getNormalizedString(actual);
                expected = Utils.getNormalizedString(expected);
                return actual.indexOf(expected) > -1;
            }

            return false;
        };

        return $filter('filter')(list, search, comparator);
    }
});
```

```css
.corpo {     
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px; 
    width: 95%;    
}

.corpo .filtros { margin-top: 50px; }    

.corpo .area-grid { padding: 30px 0px; background-color: #ededee; }
    .corpo .area-grid .container{ margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 100%; }
    .corpo .area-grid .container table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 0px; margin-top: -10px; }

        .corpo .grid .grid-header th { color: #999; cursor:pointer; font-family: "RobotoLight", Roboto-Light, sans-serif; padding: 2px 12px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; }            

        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid.linha-par { background-color: #f8f8f8; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td { border: 1px solid #ededee; border-style: solid solid; color: #333; font-size: 0.88em; line-height:0.8; padding: 2px 12px; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td+td { border-left: 2px  #ddd; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td img { height: 35px; width: 35px; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td:first-child{ border-left-style: solid; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td:last-child { background-color: #ededee; }
        
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid .icone-grid { background-color: #f5f5f5; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #c9c8c9;}
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid .icone-grid i { color: #999;}
                     
        .corpo .grid .checkbox { height: 17px; width: 17px; margin: 1px; }        
        
        .container .largura100 { width: 98%;}

        .container .largura80 { width: 78%; }
        .container .largura60 { width: 58%; }
        .container .largura40 { width: 38%; }
        .container .largura35 { width: 33%; }
        .container .largura30 { width: 28%; }
        .container .largura20 { width: 18%; }
        .container .largura15 { width: 13%; }
        .container .largura10 { width: 8%; }
        .container .largura5  { width: 3%; }

        .container .largura75 { width: 73%; }
        .container .largura50 { width: 48%; }
        .container .largura25 { width: 23%; }

        .container .largura66 { width: 64%; }
        .container .largura33 { width: 31%; }

        .container .largura100, 
        .container .largura80,
        .container .largura60,
        .container .largura40,
        .container .largura35,
        .container .largura30,
        .container .largura20,
        .container .largura15,
        .container .largura10,
        .container .largura5, 
        .container .largura75,
        .container .largura50,
        .container .largura25,
        .container .largura66,
        .container .largura33        
         {
         padding-right:1% !important;
         padding-left:1% !important;
         margin:8px 0px 8px 0px !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.5.0" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="corpo">
    <div class="filtros" ng-init="selectedTab='access'">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="campo-pesquisa">
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <input ng-model="search.$" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area-grid">
      <div class="container">
        <table class="grid">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="grid-header">
              <th ng-click="orderBy('name')" class="largura20 sort">Nome                                                 <span ng-show="orderByField == 'name'" class="fa fa-sort-{{ orderByReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </th>
              <th ng-click="orderBy('port')" class="largura10 sort">Porta                                                 <span ng-show="orderByField == 'port'" class="fa fa-sort-{{ orderByReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="col largura15"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="linhas-grid" ng-class-odd="'linha-par'" ng-class-even="'linha-impar'" ng-repeat="item in servers | normalizedFilter:search |  normalizedOrderBy:orderByField:orderByReverse as filteredList">
              <td>{{ :: item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ :: item.port }}</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-togle icone-grid" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atualizar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reiniciar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modificar IP</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Avançado</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Importar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Exportar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" class="text-center">
                <span ng-show="servers == null">Carregando...</span>
                <span ng-show="filteredList.length === 0">Nenhum registro encontrado.</span>
                <uib-pagination ng-show="filteredList.length > 0" ng-model="currentPage" total-items="filteredList.length" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" max-size="10" num-pages="numPages" boundary-links="true" previous-text="‹" next-text="›" first-text="«" last-text="»" class="pagination-sm" style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: -5px"></uib-pagination>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- fim do container -->
    </div>
    <!-- fim da área do grid -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `dropdown` class to the parent of the `dropdown-menu` element (in your case it is `td` element).

```
<td class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-togle icone-grid" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atualizar</a>
    </li>
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `position: relative` to your `.corpo .grid .linhas-grid td` will do the trick.

Currently, your dropdown menu has a `position: absolute` property, but the parent container doesn't have a `position: relative` set to it, so it will take the next parent until a relative position is found, and position 0px to the left of this container (as the dropdown menu has a `left: 0`).

Adding the relative position to the `td` parent will make it positionned according to the `td`'s position.

But as @makshh answered, adding a `.dropdown` class to the td will also do the trick and will be "cleaner" as it is the Bootstrap way to do a dropdown.

But basically both would work, as the `dropdown` class will add the `position: relative` property to the element.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filteredList = [];
   $scope.servers = [
      {
        name: 'Server 1',
        port: 5014
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 2',
        port: 5015
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 3',
        port: 5016
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 4',
        port: 5017
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 5',
        port: 5018
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 6',
        port: 5019
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 7',
        port: 5020
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 8',
        port: 8081
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 9',
        port: 8082
      },
      {
        name: 'Server 10',
        port: 8083
      }
    ];
  
  
  $scope.orderByField = "name";
  $scope.orderByReverse = false;            
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;

  $scope.orderBy = function(field) {
      if (field == $scope.orderByField)
          $scope.orderByReverse = !$scope.orderByReverse
      else {
          $scope.orderByField = field;
          $scope.orderByReverse = false;
      }
  };

  
})

.factory('Utils', function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        getNormalizedString: getNormalizedString,
        setFocus: setFocus
    }

    function getNormalizedString(str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'), "");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'), "a");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'), "ae");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'), "c");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'), "e");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'), "i");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("ñ", 'g'), "n");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'), "o");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'), "oe");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'), "u");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'), "y");
        str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'), "");
        return str;
    }

    function setFocus(id) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
            if (element)
                element.focus();
        });
    }
})

.filter('normalizedOrderBy', function(Utils, $filter) {
    return function(list, orderByField, orderByReverse) {
        function normalize(item) {
            var value = item[orderByField];
            if (typeof value === "string")
                value = Utils.getNormalizedString(value);

            // Forces the empty names to the end.
            if (value === null || value === "")
                return '~';

            return value;
        };

        return $filter('orderBy')(list, normalize, orderByReverse);
    }
})

.filter('normalizedFilter', function(Utils, $filter) {
    return function(list, search) {
        function comparator(actual, expected) {
            // Filtro vazio ou nulo.
            if (expected === "" || expected == null)
                return true;
            // Exatamente iguais.
            if (actual == expected)
                return true;

            if (typeof actual === "string" && typeof expected === "string") {
                actual = Utils.getNormalizedString(actual);
                expected = Utils.getNormalizedString(expected);
                return actual.indexOf(expected) > -1;
            }

            return false;
        };

        return $filter('filter')(list, search, comparator);
    }
});
```

```css
.corpo {     
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px; 
    width: 95%;    
}

.corpo .filtros { margin-top: 50px; }    

.corpo .area-grid { padding: 30px 0px; background-color: #ededee; }
    .corpo .area-grid .container{ margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 100%; }
    .corpo .area-grid .container table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 0px; margin-top: -10px; }

        .corpo .grid .grid-header th { color: #999; cursor:pointer; font-family: "RobotoLight", Roboto-Light, sans-serif; padding: 2px 12px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; }            

        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid.linha-par { background-color: #f8f8f8; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td { border: 1px solid #ededee; border-style: solid solid; color: #333; font-size: 0.88em; line-height:0.8; padding: 2px 12px;position: relative; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td+td { border-left: 2px  #ddd; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td img { height: 35px; width: 35px; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td:first-child{ border-left-style: solid; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid td:last-child { background-color: #ededee; }
        
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid .icone-grid { background-color: #f5f5f5; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #c9c8c9;}
        .corpo .grid .linhas-grid .icone-grid i { color: #999;}
                     
        .corpo .grid .checkbox { height: 17px; width: 17px; margin: 1px; }        
        
        .container .largura100 { width: 98%;}

        .container .largura80 { width: 78%; }
        .container .largura60 { width: 58%; }
        .container .largura40 { width: 38%; }
        .container .largura35 { width: 33%; }
        .container .largura30 { width: 28%; }
        .container .largura20 { width: 18%; }
        .container .largura15 { width: 13%; }
        .container .largura10 { width: 8%; }
        .container .largura5  { width: 3%; }

        .container .largura75 { width: 73%; }
        .container .largura50 { width: 48%; }
        .container .largura25 { width: 23%; }

        .container .largura66 { width: 64%; }
        .container .largura33 { width: 31%; }

        .container .largura100, 
        .container .largura80,
        .container .largura60,
        .container .largura40,
        .container .largura35,
        .container .largura30,
        .container .largura20,
        .container .largura15,
        .container .largura10,
        .container .largura5, 
        .container .largura75,
        .container .largura50,
        .container .largura25,
        .container .largura66,
        .container .largura33        
         {
         padding-right:1% !important;
         padding-left:1% !important;
         margin:8px 0px 8px 0px !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.5.0" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="corpo">
    <div class="filtros" ng-init="selectedTab='access'">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="campo-pesquisa">
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <input ng-model="search.$" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area-grid">
      <div class="container">
        <table class="grid">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="grid-header">
              <th ng-click="orderBy('name')" class="largura20 sort">Nome                                                 <span ng-show="orderByField == 'name'" class="fa fa-sort-{{ orderByReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </th>
              <th ng-click="orderBy('port')" class="largura10 sort">Porta                                                 <span ng-show="orderByField == 'port'" class="fa fa-sort-{{ orderByReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="col largura15"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="linhas-grid" ng-class-odd="'linha-par'" ng-class-even="'linha-impar'" ng-repeat="item in servers | normalizedFilter:search |  normalizedOrderBy:orderByField:orderByReverse as filteredList">
              <td>{{ :: item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ :: item.port }}</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-togle icone-grid" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atualizar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reiniciar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modificar IP</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Avançado</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Importar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Exportar</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" class="text-center">
                <span ng-show="servers == null">Carregando...</span>
                <span ng-show="filteredList.length === 0">Nenhum registro encontrado.</span>
                <uib-pagination ng-show="filteredList.length > 0" ng-model="currentPage" total-items="filteredList.length" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" max-size="10" num-pages="numPages" boundary-links="true" previous-text="‹" next-text="›" first-text="«" last-text="»" class="pagination-sm" style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: -5px"></uib-pagination>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- fim do container -->
    </div>
    <!-- fim da área do grid -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's it, as makshh and you said, the problem was the <td> that wasn't with the relative position. Literally applying the relative or using the dropdown class does the trick.